# Auto increment column with VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file that is generated by a program that I created to read data from a database and put it in an excel file. I have the 2nd column in my Excel sheet as an identifier column. It should start at B2 with a 1 then in B3 a 2 B4, 3 etc. How do I do this automatically?

Comment: You want auto increment at B2 (value = 1) until?

Comment: basically until the last row that has a value next to it

Comment: so, say A goes to 20, B must also go to 20 (index at B20 is of course 19)

Comment: ok, then how you want it to be triggered? workbook open?

Comment: I use a program that opens up excel, puts in all the data and executes several macro's. I want it to execute simultaneously

Comment: I want it to be triggered in a macro

Comment: one way to do it is to find out the last row, then put a formula in B2 using VBA and then pull it down using vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will increment +1 based on the row number of Column A from A2 and print the result on B2. If you want it to be triggered in a macro, you can either [call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/calling-sub-and-function-procedures) the sub from your macro or add the codes to your macro.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = i - 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```